# How can I wrap radio button in layout and not break radio group functionality?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-linearlayout, radio-group

I have a radio group with 3 radio buttons:
Like this:

```
<RadioGroup  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">  

   <RadioButton ...>  
   <TextView ....>  
   <RadioButton ...>  
   <RadioButton ...>  

</RadioGroup>
```

How could I make the first RadioButton **and** the following TextView to occupy a minHeight of Xdp?
If I wrap them in a linear layout and give the minHeight to the layout the button does not behave as it belongs to the same group as the other buttons

Comment: What do you want exactly

Comment: did you try setting min_height attribute?

Comment: @NarendraKothamire:I need both elements to occupy minHeight of Xdp.If the textview is missing then the radio button should be Xdp at least. If the textview is also there then both should be at least Xdp